# mysql query check date

Tags: mysql, sql

I cannot figure out how to write query for checking date.

For example;

Rooms table;
`room_id, number_of_rooms, checkin(date: 1/05/2012), checkout(date:14/05/2012)`;

I want to write a query which check for entered date by user (checkin and checkout date) with rooms tabel(checkin and checkout date);

The idea is to know whether period of time entered by user is between check in and check out date of rooms table

Something like this;

```
select * from romms 
where checkin and checkout date is not among user_entered_checkin and user_entered_checkeout
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe

```
SELECT * FROM rooms
WHERE (checkin IS NOT BETWEEN user_entered_checkin AND user_entered_checkout)
  AND (checkout IS NOT BETWEEN user_entered_checkin AND user_entered_checkout)
```

Comment: I am wondering whether, it can work in  situation such as `checkin =user_entered_checkin and checkout =user_entered_checkout`

Comment: Assuming you don't want those results it should. BETWEEN is inclusive (>=/<=) and this is the negation (</>).

Comment: Let me check it out, I will let you know

Answer (score 0):

If you want ranges from the table that are *completely* outside the user-entered range, then you could go like this:

```
...
WHERE checkin  > user_entered_checkout
   OR checkout < user_entered_checkin
```

If you want rows where the ranges are at least *partly* outside the user-entered range, then the condition could be this:

```
...
WHERE checkin  < user_entered_checkin
   OR checkout > user_entered_checkout
```